# Remove Dash To Dock size limit opacity

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-shell-extension, dock

I've been using dash to dock for quite some time. One thing that bothers me a bit is that I can't remove the opacity of the dock size limit "indicator" opacity like here:

[image: here]

Is there any way that i can remove it? I've tried to look into the `stylesheet.css` but still can't figure out how to remove it.

Comment: hi, what is your Ubuntu version?

Comment: are you expecting like this? https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmh2I.png are you using customized gnome-shell theme from User Shell Themes?

Comment: Yeah, i expect it like that, and i'm using gnome-shell themes, plata noir to be precise